# C# image scan pixel color

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixel

Is there any way on C# to find a pixel color every 1 second without making printscreens?
I need it for a video , to track a color .I
 can't affroid to use the bmp way as it takes too long to scan all pixels 1366x768.
Eventualy to click on it when found as the video will interact with the click.
It has to be very fast and not to take lots of ram/processor. Couldn't find a good method so far !

Comment: I'm affroid that reading one pixel once a second is not actually what you need.

Comment: I know what he wants... He just didn't put it well in words. He wants to get the color of a pixel on the screen without getting a whole screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but read the page carefully.
CITESTE BINE.

Comment: The GetPixel you linked to is the GDI version - which would need to be PINVOKEd. System.Drawing.Bitmap does implement a [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909(v=VS.85).aspx) method as well. For me it is still unclear which version you were really referring to and possibly the benefits of one over the other. I myself would probably *do* use the GDI version after getting a handle to the video graphics context, but I am not sure if all that could be done as easily and with the same performance using only managed code (i.e. System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel()).

Comment: I would extract the screen region into a bitmap with the graphics object. In my humble opinion, it is overall faster than getting all the **required** pixels...